# enableTransaction not working with J2ee Container

Tags: apache-pulsar

I get below error when I consume message in a Jboss ejb container

2022-05-18 22:37:24,699 ERROR [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation] Unable to reconnect org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivationSpec@8315a9(ra=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsResourceAdapter@10a62f0 destination=queues/Subscriber.global.globalvirtual.e2e.cmdm.changepub.Virtual destinationType=javax.jms.Queue tx=true durable=false reconnect=10 provider=java:/ACTIVEMQJMSNONXAProviderAsync user=ldcp.cmdm pass= )

javax.jms.JMSException: Please enable transactions on PulsarConnectionFactory with enableTransaction=true

After getting this error - I set enableTransaction=true and started getting different error

javax.jms.JMSException: not supported
at com.datastax.oss.pulsar.jms.PulsarConnection.createConnectionConsumer(PulsarConnection.java:685)

Answer (score 0):

the error is in createConnectionConsumer.
This is the method called by the JBoss container.

This method is currently not implemented
https://github.com/datastax/pulsar-jms/blob/96606d0f22a1af8fdde0c5eff0f5dde086d9862c/pulsar-jms/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/pulsar/jms/PulsarConnection.java#L685

the implementation should be quite straighforward.

There are integration tests for Payara and Apache TomEE but JBoss is still not covered.

Please open an issue on github.